# IdentityServer4 and custom Client entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I’m using IdentityServer4 with .net core application.
i made some customer logic regarding the user entity in my app, I’m using .AddAspNetIdentity() to set my user entity to ApplicationUser class which drives from IdentityUser.

i implemented IClientStore to load my users.
but there i have to return IdentityServer4.Models.Client type, this is not good because now i have to maintain 2 different types(IdentityServer4.Models.Client,ApplicationUser).

is there a way to use my class ApplicationUser cross the system?

Comment: you can derive the `ApplicationUser` from the `Client` type like 'class ApplicationUser : Client` and return the ApplicationUser instance.

Comment: the thing is they have very different field, i prefer to use only in ApplicationUser.      is it possible?

Comment: Clients are not users, and you shouldn't confuse the two. A user could be a client, but it also may not be, and there's tons of other things that aren't users that can be clients. IdentityServer *intentionally* doesn't have a concept of users specifically for this reason. If a user just so happens to also be a client, then you can simply assign them a client. Your user management should be completely separate, though.